# get value from all array var in a php file

Tags: php, arrays, var

I have a php file (shortcode-config.php) where I declared some var array.

I want to get for each var in this file some values in each array.

shortcode-config.php :

```
$theme_shortcodes['one_half'] = array( 
    'no_preview' => true,
    'title'=>__('One Half (1/2)', 'textdomain' ), 
    'shortcode' => '[theme_one_half boxed="{{boxed}}" centered_text="{{centered_text}}" last_column="{{last_column}}"] {{content}} [/themeone_one_half]',
    'popup_title' => __('One Half (1/2) column', 'textdomain'),
    'shortcode_icon' => __('fa-list')
);

$theme_shortcodes['one_third'] = array( 
    'no_preview' => true,
    'title'=>__('One third (1/3)', 'textdomain' ), 
    'shortcode' => '[theme_one_third boxed="{{boxed}}" centered_text="{{centered_text}}" last_column="{{last_column}}"] {{content}} [/themeone_one_half]',
    'popup_title' => __('One third (1/3) column', 'textdomain'),
    'shortcode_icon' => __('fa-list')
);
```

And in my other php file I get the var, but currently the only one I defined in `$popup` (I don't know how to loop inside the file without knowing name var in `$theme_shortcodes['']`):

```
    <?php
    class theme_sc_data {

    var $conf;
    var $popup;
    var $shortcode;
    var $popup_title;
    var $has_child;

    function __construct( $popup ) {
        $this->conf = dirname(__FILE__) . '/shortcodes-config.php';
        $this->popup = $popup;
        $this->formate_shortcode();
    }
    function formate_shortcode() {
        require_once( $this->conf );
        $this->shortcode = $theme_shortcodes[$this->popup]['shortcode'];
        $this->popup_title = $theme_shortcodes[$this->popup]['popup_title'];
        $this->shortcode_icon = $theme_shortcodes[$this->popup]['shortcode_icon'];
    }
}
$popup = 'one_half';
$shortcode = new theme_sc_data($popup);
?>
```

I want to output from `shortcode-config.php` something like this for each var:

```
<span><i class="fa <?php echo $theme_shortcodes[$this->popup]['shortcode_icon']; ?>"></i><?php echo $theme_shortcodes[$this->popup]['popup_title']; ?></span>
```

I want to do this to automatically fill a list from all this var with their attributes

Comment: Is the file included properly? What are trying to get?

Comment: The files are correctly included for sure.I can access to them. I want to get all var `$theme_shortcodes[]` name and for each in the array `popup_title` `shortcode_icon` for example. Currently I push `$popup` var into my function and I correctly get one of my var in shortcode-config.phph file. I want to automated this without $popup var...

Comment: So you want to create theme_sc_data instance for every $theme_shortcodes items, right?

Comment: Yes. Currently I need to know the name of the var. Them to push it thanks to `$popup` var in my function `theme_sc_data`. I want to loop inside the file and get all `$theme_shortcodes[]` var and array paramaters without to know the name of my var `$theme_shortcodes[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/shortcodes-config.php');
$shortcode = array();
if(!empty($theme_shortcodes)){
   foreach($theme_shortcodes as $key=>$val){
         $shortcode[] = new theme_sc_data($key,$val); 
   }
}
```

here $key will be `one_third`,`one_half` etc.. and $val will hold the array. Now `$shortcode` will be an array of objects. I think `$key` has no importance in your class function, but still it is passed for if you need any use.

And change your class to avoid the including again to

```
class theme_sc_data {

    var $conf;
    var $key;
    var $shortcode_icon;
    var $popup_title;
    var $has_child;

    function __construct( $key,$val ) {
        $this->conf = dirname(__FILE__) . '/shortcodes-config.php';
        $this->key = $key; // actually of no use now, but may be in future
        $this->formate_shortcode($val);
    }
    function formate_shortcode($val) {
        $this->shortcode = $val['shortcode'];
        $this->popup_title = $val['popup_title'];
        $this->shortcode_icon = $val['shortcode_icon'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I don't understand how I can output echo for example `$val['popup_title'];` ?

Comment: `foreach($theme_shortcodes as $key=>$val){  echo $val['title']; }`

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake from me! It works great of course! Thanks a lot!